# Java: When reading a text file, how can i read that specific line which contains a certain string?

Tags: java

```
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MANIFEST.MF"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(everything);
```

This is what i use to read all text within the file, im curious how i can change this in order for me to read a certain line that contains for example: "Main-Class".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read every line and when you get a line which starts with what you want, you have that line.

Comment: You cannot get that line without looping through each line. You'll have to check each line with a `line.contains(...)` and then break out of the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Check to see whether your line variable contains the string you're looking for, then exit the while loop...or do whatever you want with the line.  You may also want to change your code to this...a little more concise and readable.

```
String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
```

Comment: if(line.toLowerCase().contains("main")) i added this right after the beginning of the loop, and it seems to work. However i cannot exit the while loop for some reason.. It keeps printing that line

Comment: Use "break;" at the end of the true condition

Answer (score 0):

To find first line which contains "Main-Class":

```
try ( BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("MANIFEST.MF")) ) {

  String line = null;
  while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
    if ( line.contains("Main-Class") ) break;
  }

  if ( line != null ) {
    // line was found
  } else {
    // line was not found
  }
}
```

To find all lines which contain "Main-Class":

```
StringBuilder matchedLines = new StringBuilder();
try ( BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("MANIFEST.MF")) ) {

  String line = null;
  while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
    if ( line.contains("Main-Class") ) {
      matchedLines.append(line);
      matchedLines.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
  }
}
// ...
System.out.println("Matched Lines:");
System.out.println(matchedLines.toString());
```